# How to call function inside another function in qgis python plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I am developing qgis plugin.

```
class HyperspectralClassifier:
 """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

  def __init__(self, iface):
  .
  .

    self.dlg.pb8.clicked.connect(self.plotspect)
  def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
    try:
        window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(np.int(order))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
    # precompute coefficients
    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    # pad the signal at the extremes with
    # values taken from the signal itself
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')       

  def plotspect(self):
   #QMessageBox.information(None, "Clicked coords", " Row: " + str(row) + " Column: " + str(column) )     
   iinf=self.dlg.iin.text()
   img=gdal.Open(iinf)
   inputArray=img.ReadAsArray()
   ia1=inputArray[4:195,141,194]  
   ia1=savitzky_golay(ia1, 51, 3)           
   plt.plot(ia1,label="Original Spectrum")
   plt.show()
```

**but it  gives error like this: global name 'savitzky_golay' is not defined** 
what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference it from within the class using `self` to get your current instance.  Also, since you are not using the instance itself in the `savitsky_golay()` method, you should consider making it a [static method](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods).  Try the following:

```
class HyperspectralClassifier:
 """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

  def __init__(self, iface):
    self.dlg.pb8.clicked.connect(self.plotspect)

  @staticmethod
  def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
    try:
        window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(np.int(order))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
    # precompute coefficients
    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    # pad the signal at the extremes with
    # values taken from the signal itself
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')   


  def plotspect(self):
   #QMessageBox.information(None, "Clicked coords", " Row: " + str(row) + " Column: " + str(column) )     
   iinf=self.dlg.iin.text()
   img=gdal.Open(iinf)
   inputArray=img.ReadAsArray()
   ia1=inputArray[4:195,141,194]  
   ia1=self.savitzky_golay(ia1, 51, 3)           
   plt.plot(ia1,label="Original Spectrum")
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks it works.but we need to add self in function like this.                    No need to write @staticmethod                                                                                 def savitzky_golay(self,y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):

Comment: You do not need to add `self` in this case since the method does not require anything from the class or instance.  I don't use QGIS, so I'm not familiar with their plugin framework but just based on how Python works you could turn `savitzky_golay()` into a function in this script or in it's own module and import it in here for usage as long as it is in your `PYTHONPATH`.